# WPF User Control Dependency Property not working when bound to a ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have two user-controls: a LocationTreeView, and a LocationPicker. The LocationTreeView organizes Locations into a tree structure. Because of the number of locations involved, only parts of the tree are loaded at once (one level at a time as items are expanded).

The LocationPicker is little more than a textblock with a button that opens a modal window with a LocationTreeView on it.

When I bind my LocationPicker's "SelectedLocation" property to my Viewmodel, it works fine. When I bind my LocationTreeView to the viewmodel, the binding doesn't seem to have any effect at all. When I bind my LocationTreeView to a "dummy" LocationPicker (which is bound to my viewmodel) it works.
How can I get my LocationTreeView to bind to my viewmodel?

```
public partial class LocationTreeView: UserControl
{
    public EventHandler LocationChanged;
    ...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLocationProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLocation",typeof(Location), typeof(LocationTreeView),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedLocationChanged));
    ...

    public static void SelectedLocationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         LocationTreeView sender = (d as LocationTreeView);
         Location loc = e.NewValue as Location;
         //Navigate the treeview to the selected location
         sender.LoadLTreeViewPathToLocation(loc);
    }

    public Location SelectedLocation
    {
         get { return (Location)GetValue(SelectedLocationProperty); }
         set
         {
              if (SelectedLocation != value)
              {
                 SetValue(SelectedLocationProperty, value);
                 if (LocationChanged != null)
                 {
                     LocationChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                 }
              }
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

Binding on this control works fine when bound to another control, but not when bound to my viewmodel. I've set a breakpoint in the SelectedLocationChanged callback, it doesn't seem to get fired when I set the viewmodel property (which DOES implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public partial class LocationPicker: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLocationProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLocation",typeof(Location), typeof(LocationPicker),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    ...

    public Location SelectedLocation
    {
         get { return (Location)GetValue(SelectedLocationProperty); }
         set { SetValue(SelectedLocationProperty, value); }
    }
    ...

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // create a window with a locationtreeview on it. Set the treeview's
         // selectedlocation property, open the window, wait for the window to close,
         //  set this.SelectedLoctation to the treeview's selected location.
    }
}
```

I apologize for the leaving out so much code. My work enviroment prevents me from being able to copy/paste.

I've left out the code for the ViewModel. I am quite confident that it is not the issue.

---

Update:
The LocationTreeView has a ViewModel that is set in the xaml

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <VM:LocationTreeViewViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The LocationPicker does not have a ViewModel.
On the window that I am using the controls, the xaml looks something like this

```
<Widow.DataContext>
    <VM:TestWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
...
<UC:LocationPicker x:Name="picker" SelectedLocation="{Binding Location}" /> 

<!-- this does not work -->
<UC:LocationTreeView SelectedLocaiton="{Binding Location}" />

<!-- but this works --->
<UC:LocationTreeView SelectedLocaiton="{Binding SelectedLocation, ElementName=picker}" />
...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please show the code of Binding?

Comment: I won't be able to verify this until tomorrow, but I believe the issue is that when the LocationTreeView is bound to the viewmodel, it uses the LocationTreeView's default DataContext rather than the DataContext for the window. This would explain why it works when bound to another control, because setting the ElementName (or RelativeSource, etc.) within the binding expression would explictly set the DataContext for that expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to data bind from your view model to the `LocationTreeView`, then you should use the property in the view model to data bind to. If your view model had a property named `SelectedLocationInViewModel` in it, then you should use that to data bind to:

```
<UC:LocationTreeView SelectedLocation="{Binding SelectedLocationInViewModel}" />
```

I think that I see what your problem is now... you want to define some properties in the `UserControl` and data bind to them, but *also* data bind to properties from the view model that is set as the `DataContext`. You need to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to do that... just look at the `Binding Path`s in these examples:

To data bind to properties declared in a `UserControl` *from within the `UserControl`*:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
```

To data bind to properties declared in any object set as the `DataContext`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyName}" />
```